# Firebase Authentication with Flutter not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a signup page which should give an error message if user with particular email id already exist. But it's not working.

```
signUp() {
    if (formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
      Map<String, String> userDataMap = {
        "name": usernameC.text,
        "email": emailC.text
      };

      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });

      authMethods.signUp(emailC.text, passwordC.text).then((value) {
        databaseMethods.uploadUserData(userDataMap);
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChatRoom()));
      });
    }
  }
```

It calls the signUp() function from auth.dart given below

```
 UserData? _userFromFirebase(User? user) {
    return user != null ? UserData(userid: user.uid) : null;
  }

 Future signUp(String email, String pass) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: pass);
      User? user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebase(user);
    } catch (e) {
print(e}
  }
```

Every time I signup with same email it doesn't give any error.

Answer (score 0):

If you sign up with the same email you should get this message:
`[firebase_auth/email-already-in-use] The email address is already in use by another account.`

I use `print(e.hashCode)` and then use this hash code to show an error message.

Comment: Its not working, I don't know why its not giving any error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried this method and it worked out. Just added null check for the "value" attribute in.

```
authMethods.signUp(emailC.text, passwordC.text).then((value)
```

It was returning null without any other message. That's why I was unable to see the error.